# XAML fast Printing on Bill Printer (IBM SureMark 4610)

Tags: performance, xaml, printing

I have the problem, that my bill printer is printing very slow with one line per second instead of 52 lines per second. My print object is a WPF XAML-FixedPage:

```
public virtual void Print(FixedPage page)
{
    PrintTicket pTicket = PrintingQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;

    // Print without dialog
    PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog
    {
        PrintQueue = PrintingQueue, // Type PrintQueue of the selected printer
        PrintTicket = pTicket       // Type PrintTicket
    };

    pDialog.PrintVisual(page, "Print it");
}
```

The XAML-Objects are printed as I want but on a bill printer like the IBM SureMark 4610 the printing is very slow. This is because the printer prints the XAML FixedPage in Graphic Mode which is one line per second and not 52 lines per second. IBM writes that the Printer prints in graphic mode when other fonts than the three embedded (Font A 10pt, Font B 12pt, Font C ?pt) are used.

I thried than setting the font with FontFamily="Font A" and the Size with FontSize="10"

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="Time: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Font A" FontSize="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WorktimeBegin, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Font A" FontSize="10" />
    <TextBlock Text=" - " HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WorktimeEnd, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Font A" FontSize="10" />
 </DockPanel>
```

but the printer do not switch to the non graphic mode. It is further slow printing.

Can someone tell me how I can fast print an XAML FixedPage on a bill printer?
Has someone successfully done it before?
I think the clou are the embedded three fonts but they are not used correctly so that the printer can use them.

Thanks
René

Comment: This is normal, you are using the printer driver and it is sending individual pixels to the printer.  It is only fast if you send escape codes, called "Native mode" in the IBM literature.  You [need this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) and the programming manual for the printer to know what codes to send.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer and the link. I will look at it but we are not programming for exactly this IBM Suremark 4611. It's only a reference bill printer and our customers can habe other printers. Therefore I think the slow graphic mode printing is the onliest solution. Maybe (the 4611 ist an old printer which was cheap) newer bill printer have better graphic mode support.

Comment: All POS printers behave like this.  Locking in the specific model you are going to use is *very* important.